WPF DataGrid and Delete Button
`So I am trying to use the DataGrid and create a Column Template to add a delete button. The problem is that the row is databound to a record that in my observableCollection, but the binding of the button has to be bound to the viewmodel and not to the object of the row. if a datacontext is added to the button, then the button will fire. However the SelectedValue for the Grid that is bound to a property ends up null if that is done.
Here is the code.
< DataGrid x: Name = "ActualDataGrid"  DockPanel.Dock = "Top"
   ItemsSource = "{Binding ActualData}"
   Margin = "5,10,5,5"
   FontSize = "14"
   FontWeight = "Bold"
   Background = "WhiteSmoke"
   AlternatingRowBackground = "AliceBlue"
   VerticalAlignment = "Top"
   HorizontalAlignment = "Stretch"
   AutoGenerateColumns = "False"
   GridLinesVisibility = "Horizontal"
   ColumnHeaderHeight = "45"
   SelectionMode = "Extended"
   CanUserAddRows = "True"
   CanUserDeleteRows = "False"
   SelectedValue = "{Binding SelectedResult}"
    Height = "{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ProjectedDataGrid}"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility = "Visible" >
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle >
      <Style TargetType = "DataGridColumnHeader" >
      <Setter Property = "ContentTemplate" >
      <Setter.Value >
      <DataTemplate >
      <TextBlock TextWrapping = "Wrap" Text = "{Binding}" FontWeight = "Bold" ></ TextBlock >
      </ DataTemplate >
      </ Setter.Value >
      </ Setter >
      </ Style >
    </ DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle >
    <DataGrid.Columns >
      < DataGridTextColumn Header = "Num" Width = "50" Binding = "{Binding Path= num}" />
      < DataGridTextColumn Header = "Notes" Width = "*" Binding = "{Binding Path= description}" />
      < DataGridTemplateColumn Header = "Delete" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
      <DataTemplate >
       <Button Command = "{Binding DeleteCommand}"
         Margin = "3" Background = "Transparent" BorderThickness = "0" >
       <Button.DataContext >    <=== Optional does not work because selected value nulled.
            <future:VmModel x:Name = "VM" />
        </ Button.DataContext >
      <Button.Content >
           <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind = "TrashCanOutline" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
         </Button.Content>
       </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

DeleteCommand = new RelayCommand(param => CanDelete(param), param => Delete(param));

private bool CanDelete(object o)
{
    return true;// _selectedResult != null;
}

private ICommand _deleteCommand;
public ICommand DeleteCommand
{
   get
   {
      return _deleteCommand;
  }
  set
 { 
   _saveCommand = value;
  }
}

private void Delete(object result)
{
}
private FutureChartData _selectedResult;
public FutureChartData SelectedResult
{
    get { return _selectedResult; }
    set
    {
        _selectedResult = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedResult");
    }
}

 < Button Command = "{Binding DeleteCommand}"
  Margin = "3" Background = "Transparent" BorderThickness = "0" >
  < Button.DataContext >    <=== Optional does not work because selected value nulled.
      <future:VmModel x:Name = "VM" />
  </ Button.DataContext >
< Button.Content >
   < materialDesign:PackIcon Kind = "TrashCanOutline" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
 </Button.Content>`
</Button>


i think you are over complicating this..... the DeleteCommand is on the main DataContext, right?  Why does that not work?  if you only want the Delete button enabled when there is a selected value in the Grid then bind the Buttons IsEnabled to something like "HasSelectedItem" boolean on the vm

You can use the built-in functionality to delete items. The DataGrid exposes a routed command DeleteCommand. Just use that: <Button Command="{x:Static DataGrid.DeleteCommand}" />

You could bind to the DataContext of the parent DataGrid (the view model) using a {RelativeSource}:
    <Button Command = "{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}" ... />


So this is the final solution which did work. 
Had to walk away from it for a while to get it. 
The DataContext is the entire viewmodel at the UserControl Level..
The ItemSource is a collection of object databound to the DataGrid 
Which are part of the ViewModel for the UserControl. 
The Goal of all of this was to enforce the MVVM pattern and not use
any event handlers in the code behind file. This is needs for 
testability and code coverage should that be implemented later.

    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                    AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, 
                    Path=DataContext.DeleteRowCommand}"  
                    Margin="3" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon  Kind="TrashCanOutline" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                             


That did not work. The only solution has been to use the event handler in the code behind file. Databinding does not work because the row is bound to the record. the button has to be bound to the datacontext's viewmodel. Doing this caused the SelectedValue to come back null when the button is fired and caught in the viewmodel. If I am able to catch the button fire, then the SelectedValue comes back null and the button fire becomes worthless without information to work on.

You're making this far more complicated than is necessary. mm8 already gave you the correct solution yesterday - use relative source binding to bind the button to a command on the main view model.

Of course it works - relative binding for this functionality is a standard WPF / MVVM construct that I've used in many different applications. Check out my blog post [peregrinesview.uk/wpf-data-binding/] for a working example.
